# Microservices design

Tags: java, spring, microservices

I am new to microservices and I am getting a hardtime in understanding what they exactly are. I would take an example situation, if you can break it down to how microservices should be written for this scenario then it woud be really great.

Scenario: I have to work with two content management systems: Documentum and IBM FileNet.

For each content management system I want to write an implementation to -

1. Create a new file or a folder.
2. Update a fileor a folder.
3. Delete a fileor a folder.
4. Update fileor folder metadata.
5. Search a file.
6. Get content of a file.
7. Create and Update permission sets applied on file or folder.
   etc.

How should I break this down to microservices? 
Should I write implementation for each content management systems in a seperate microservice?

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: no the microservices are distribution of systems load balancing and a lot of traffic and building nodes to run each service

Comment: so they discover each other and work as different units, and other use cases for eneterprise solution where you use different platforms

Comment: example situation is that you have a have a legacy project from 10 years that is still bringing you money or something. You are implementing new solution that is using your old software. network solutions too

Comment: but not your case in my opinion as you will have to write absolutely everything different in your design

Comment: thumbs up - lets other people participate in the discusion too

Comment: you should better explain in your question why you chose Microservices?

Comment: not that you are reading about microservices and you want to apply them to first thing that you need.

Comment: better read one full tutorial and do your project - changing the names in the tutorial project with your own ideas

Comment: 1. This is obviously off-topic for SO. 2. Microservices should be centered around business capabilities. You did not indicate you have more than one. You don't need microservices.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you will have to write each content management system as a separate micro-service & expose REST end-points so that they can scale individually without being inter-dependent on each other

PS : For understanding micro-services, http://microservices.io/ is the ideal place to start. Also articles of https://microserviceweekly.com/ would be helpful in your micro-services architecture journey

Comment: What is "microservices" about it at all?